# I get an unexpected outcome for square array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, unsigned

I get the outcome for squares

`squares = [ 512, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49 ]`.

I know I reached the boundaries of my limit but where did 512 come from? Can you give me an explanation of all the individual steps involved in the error occurring?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned squares[8];
    unsigned cubes[8];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        squares[i] = i * i;
        cubes[i] = i * i * i;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you write cubes[8] you are actually writing to squares[0] because of the way the arrays are layed out in memory.

Comment: oh ok thanks mcuh appreciate it.

Comment: see my answer to understand why *undefined behavior* questions are not answered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the same thing as everyone is saying. It is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and you should not do that.

Now, you would ask whether the **undefined behavior** is the reason for whatever is happening.

I would say, **Yes, probably.**

---

Now, you may think this is an easy escape from answering the question.

It may be, but..

The main problem with these kind of question is, **it is very hard to re-create the same case and investigate what actually made it behave the way it did**. Because **undefined behavior**, well, behaves in a very undefined way.

That is the reason people do not try answering these kind of questions, and people advise to stay away from **undefined behavior** territory.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing memory beyond the limit

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i <8; i++)
```

Remember `unsigned squares[8];` allows you to **legally** access `squares[0]` upto `squares[7]`

> I know i reached the boundaries of my limit but where did 512 come
>   from.

The consequences of illegal memory access is undefined as per **ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.10->fn109**

> Two objects may be adjacent in memory because they are adjacent
>   elements of a larger array or adjacent members of a structure with no
>   padding between them, or because the implementation chose to place
>   them so, even though they are unrelated. If prior invalid pointer
>   operations (such as accesses outside array bounds) produced undefined
>   behavior, subsequent comparisons also produce undefined behavior

You may use a debugger(say gdb) or an instrumentation framework(say valgrind) to find where the value came from. Here 512 looks like the cube of 8 but there is no guarantee that you will get the same value on the next run.  Morever, there is a chance that the program might crash.

Comment: Yes i Know but where did 512 come from out of curiosity of understanding the program better.

Answer (score 1):

> *I know i reached the boundaries of my limit*

Then you **should** know the consequences, too. Accessing out of bound memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Stay within the valid memory limit. Use

```
for (int i = 0; i <8; i++)
```

Comment: so it randomly gave 512 ?

Comment: @PrinceofPersia Yes, it's UB. __Don't do that__.